# How to get your custom content drawn in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder, swift, ios8

I watched the "What's New in Interface Builder" session video and tried to replicate the code that was showed but unfortunately when I assign a view to my custom class which has `@IBDesignable` I get 2 errors:

Main.storyboard: error: Live Views: Failed to update auto layout status: The bundle “swiftTest” couldn’t be loaded because its executable isn’t loadable.

Main.storyboard: error: Live Views: Failed to render instance of _TtC9swiftTest14ControllerView: The bundle “swiftTest” couldn’t be loaded because its executable isn’t loadable.

Later on in the video I saw that to have Live Views you have to make these steps:
1. Create framework
2. Create class
3. Mark as designable

How do I make the 1st step?

Thanks

Comment: this is a bug, please file a radar

Comment: I have 2 errors like that, but it still actually runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it at the moment (*prior to Xcode 6 Beta 3*), @IBDesignable will only work from a view declared in a *separate* framework target.
However, I also struggled to add it because I had no "plus" button as described in various links (*because the Hide Project & Target Lists arrow option was toggled off*).

So, select your current project target, then just use the xcode menu options: 
*Editor > Add target...*
Then select 
*Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework* etc.

By the way, to test @IBDesignable, this tutorial worked perfectly as a starting point:
http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

One small but important thing to note in that tutorial (if you follow it onscreen instead of following on to its full github code listing) is that your view class must be prepended/decorated with @IBDesignable, e.g.
    class CustomView : UIView {...}
should be
    @IBDesignable class CustomView : UIView {...}

Comment: At first I thought there was no plus button, from watching that WWDC video, but it is in the second column. Click on The top icon in the leftmost view, the one with the Xcode icon that says "4 Targets" or however many, then to the right the details of the project will appear. The left of that will have a column with PROJECT and TARGETS, and at the bottom a + - and search box.

Comment: As of Xcode 6 Beta 3, you don't have to create a separate framework anymore to use `@IBDesignable`.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Ley, I've tested it and found the same to be true on my side - have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: One small caveat: In beta 3, using a Bool type with @IBinspectable no longer works. E.g. `@IBInspectable var isBroken: Bool = true` will not appear in the IB.

Comment: @zacjordaan this appears to be working in later betas, at least for Objective-C projects.

Comment: Why all Apple does related to the SDK is complex like hell? What about simply allowing dragging and dropping images to the parts of the object you want to customize. Lets say a UISlider. You drag an image for the thumb, an image for the rail, etc. C'mon Apple. Make things easy.

Answer (score 2):

You should make new framework as a target for current project and add your live views in this framework. On General tab on main target you will see your framework in Embedded Binaries section.

Comment: As was shown on "What's New in Interface Builder" session you should move to Build settings, click plus button on left bottom and select Cocoa Touch Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I had a project with live views working and at one point I also had these error messages. This went away for me when closing XCode and restarting, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

---

> It is **working very well** (*and easily*) for me with *Swift* in **Xcode 6 Beta 5**.

---

I've confirmed that with *Xcode 6 Beta 5* I did ***not*** need to add any frameworks (for example, Cocoa Touch framework option under frameworks in the dialog that appears when adding a new project target). Nor did I need to add IBDesignable.h to the project.  *Both seem to be outdated requirements as per the the weheartswift.com write-up linked in the initial answer to the question.*

All I needed to do was:

1. Prefix **class** definition of my custom Swift class source file
   with keyword **@IBDesignable**
2. Prefix vars I wanted to show up in IB Attributes Inspector with **@IBInspectable** (IB recognizes several common variable types).

Then, after assigning my custom component's (UIControl subclass) name to IB's "Class" name file (under Identity Inspector tab, in right pane) replacing "UIView" -- e.g. the class name of the UIView placeholder object I originally dragged onto the IB VC's view -- upon selecting my custom component from the Content View component list in IB, I saw all my custom class' inspectable items show up in the IB Attributes Inspector!! *Very* cool.

---

*Note: At first XCode would only allow me to prefix one variable with @IBInspectable. It showed errors on subsequent ones. Then, suddenly it seemed to work, and no more problems after that. Not sure if it was a typo or just took Xcode awhile to re-index my project and pre-compile or parse the code.*

Comment: Ultimately I found it slowed my development too much. Apparently it causes Xcode to recompile things too much and with Swift, trying to cross reference things all the time, and tendencies for errors to cascade, and sometimes mischaracterizing things or hiding errors but getting into dysfunctional states because of them, it was untenable, so I decided not to use this interesting/promising but not ready for prime time feature.

Answer (score 0):

I code about @IBDesignable & @IBInspectable,

firstly, I got two errors like you,

then, I change the code I wrote,

you can checkout the code from my [github](https://github.com/kingiol/IBDesignableDemo)

Good Luck.